# Matplotlib errorbar with only xerrors - wrong legend symbol

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.errorbar(0., 0., xerr=1., capsize=3, capthick=3, label="wrong shape")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I get

[image]

I consider this to be incorrect, as the legend symbol has the line going beyond the endcaps to the left and right. How can  I fix it so that the legend symbol is simply `|--|` not `-|--|-`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib works fine in this case. You have to use keyword `handlelength` to specify the length of your line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.errorbar(0., 0., xerr=1., capsize=3, capthick=3, label="wrong shape")
plt.legend(handlelength=1.)
plt.show()
```

[image]